# Can you deep fry chicken in a 6.75qt dutch oven?

Tags: chicken, deep-frying, dutch-oven

I wanna fry up some chicken and I'm wondering if my 6.75 Le Creuset will be large enough. Assuming it's half to two-thirds of the way full (3-4 QTs of oil). Does anyone have experience with this?

Edit: Clarifying my question a little, I'm asking about frying chicken pieces, not an entire chicken. Also, I understand that I can simply find a small pot with several cups of oil and fry up an entire chicken 1 piece at a time. I was hoping that my dutch oven would be large enough to at least get through a whole chicken in 2-3 batches (3-4 pieces at a time).

Comment: From a safety standpoint, you should never fill a pan over a third to just under half full of oil for frying. This helps to prevent boil-overs which can be extremely dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of the chicken, and how much you want to cook at one time.

Place the bird (or pieces) in your pot and fill the pot to about 3/4 full *with water*.

Remove the chicken and measure the water...this is how much oil to use.

If the chicken isn't covered in the water at 3/4 full (this will probably be the case) remove pieces and work backwards till the water and chicken are at a safe level). After replacing the water with oil you will need to work in batches (which is probably what you will need to do, you will probably be well served to do about a 1/2 chicken at a time.).

---

For what it is worth I recently purchased an infra-red propane 'fryer' that does an excellent job on a whole chicken (or turkey).

Comment: Yeah, I thought "a chicken" but the question seems to be about pieces... I hope. :D

Comment: @Catija Sorry about that, looking back over my question I can see where the confusion was. Edited my question for clarity!